# TcpClient só recebe a primeira mensagem enquanto conectado

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Estou desenvolvendo um programa por *hobby*, a fim de entender como funciona o `TcpClient`. Pois bem, estou fazendo um programa que de tempo em tempo recebe um pacote de um programa secundário e envia um OK de volta, confirmando que a conexão ainda está estabelecida.

Na primeira requisição, o meu programa envia o OK normalmente. Porém, na segunda requisição, ele já não funciona mais. É como se ele não tivesse recebido pacote nenhum do *client*, mas eu consigo ver neste segundo que o pacote foi enviado.

Segue abaixo o meu server:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int InternalLoop = 0;
        bool Finished = false;
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 10000);
        int requestCount = 0;
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        serverSocket.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            bool LoopReceive = true;
            bool LoopSend = false;

            Console.WriteLine(" :::: SERVER STARTED OK");
            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine(" :::: CONNECTED TO CLIENT");
            requestCount = 0;
            NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

            string Packettosend = "";

            while (LoopReceive == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Gets the Client Packet
                    requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                    byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[128];
                    networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length);
                    string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);

                    Packettosend = "ALIVE";
                    Console.WriteLine(" ::: SENDING ALIVE PACKET");
                    LoopReceive = false;
                    LoopSend = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }

            while (LoopSend == true || InternalLoop < 2)
            {
                try
                {
                    InternalLoop += 1;
                    if (Packettosend == "ALIVE")
                    {
                        Byte[] sendBytes1 = { 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 };
                        networkStream.Write(sendBytes1, 0, sendBytes1.Length);
                        networkStream.Flush();

                        LoopReceive = true;
                        LoopSend = false;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Se eu fechar o *client* ou o *server* e abrir novamente, o server recebe novamente o pacote esperado e envia de volta o OK, mas somente na primeira requisição.

Já procurei algo similar antes de criar este tópico, mas nada serviu.

Comment: Consegue colocar o código do `client` também? Fiz um `client` para teste e funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Boa Tarde!!
Tente usar um Finally após o primeiro catch.
Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }

finally
            {
                   tcpListener.Stop();
            }